# Central Digital ID O365 (Exchange Online)

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, digital-signatures, exchangeonline

Is there any way to define and deploy a Digital ID for all users centrally?
We`re using Exchange Online.

As of now I only see the possibility to open Outlook for every user and apply for a Digital ID.

Thankful

Comment: As of now it is not possible, as per Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your Exchange Online environment is configured and how much money you wish to spend. What we build for a customer used a 3rd party S/MIME Autoenrollment feature and active directory features.

So here are the basics implementation steps:

1. Implement an active directory triggered public trusted certification authority. There might be more but we used the one from [Comodo](https://enterprise.comodo.com/security-solutions/digital-certificates/certificate-manager): Feature: *Automatic Deployment with Microsoft Active Directory or CSV File Upload. Rapid client certificate distribution and management achieve tight integration with many types of directory-based employee/device management systems.*
2. Configure the Exchange Hybrid server, so that the S/Mime elements are synced, so the user can pick them up from the GAL (see Microsoft documentation [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2014/12/15/how-to-configure-smime-in-office-365/))
3. Part 3 was the tricky part and really depends on your local environment and how you can deploy something to the client PCs. The customer was using a Software Management suite which allowed us to write a small plugin which can put the correct certificate on the user PC even the user is working from home without a constant direct connection to the active directory.
4. The part 4 was the tricky one, we need a way to push the certificate also to the mobile devices. The customer was using AirWatch which has an API and we where able to push the S/Mime certificate to the mobile device clients.

By the way, some important lesson here: Make a BACKUP from any S/Mime certificate you will push to the user.